# How can I disable only specific errors in Eclipse/Geppetto?

Tags: eclipse, puppet

I am using Geppetto 2.1.2 build R201202021616, which is based off the Eclipse engine. I'm using the standalone install, rather than the Eclipse plugin version.

I have a few common warnings that show up in my puppet files, due to the module I am coding being part of a larger project that Geppetto is not aware of.

I would like to have it ignore certain warnings.

I've found how to disable all errors and warnings, and how to disable based on types such as "Xtext Check", but this doesn't quite cover what I want to do.

The two specific warnings I want to make it ignore are:

> Hyphen '-' in name only unofficially supported in some puppet
>   versions.

and

> Unqualified and Unknown variable: '$<varname>'

Can this be done, and if so how? I've only been able to find info on disabling/ignoring much broader categories of warnings and errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those errors/markers are configurable by a user in Geppetto (2.2.0 is the current version). Suggest you log enhancement requests with [the Geppetto issue tracker](https://github.com/cloudsmith/geppetto/issues). (The checks that *can* be configured error/warning/ignore are found under Preferences/Puppet and these tabs are called *Potential Problems*, and *Stylistic Problems*.)

There are two tricks that can be used to introduce variables that are missing because all modules are not present.

- You can add those variables to a "platform" .pptp file as described in the Geppetto FAQ Entry [How do I make global variables known to Geppetto?](http://cloudsmith.github.com/geppetto/faq.html#2011/11/01/how-do-i-add-global-variables).

or

- Create a dummy puppet project, add a manifest and define the variables with dummy values. Then add the dummy project as a "project dependency". This will expose the variables to all code in the project and variables will be resolved.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. I'll get a request filed shortly, as well as update my IDE.